# "Transport-level Error" using SQL Server Stored Procedure and Cursor

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor

I have created a stored procedure for `auto follow` users and this procedure is already on the server. In my database, there are 20,000+ users. This store procedure uses **Cursor**.

I am getting this error **A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)**"

This is my stored procedure .

```
                DECLARE @UserIdF Int
            DECLARE @UserId Int

        DECLARE csrAutoFollow CURSOR FOR
        SELECT  TOP (1) userid FROM dbo.users where  IsFUser = 1  ORDER BY NEWID()

        OPEN csrAutoFollow
            FETCH NEXT FROM csrAutoFollow INTO @UserIdF

            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                            DECLARE csrauto CURSOR FOR
                            SELECT userid FROM dbo.Users WHERE IsFUser IS NULL 

                            OPEN csrauto
                                FETCH NEXT FROM csrauto INTO @UserId

                            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
                            BEGIN       

                                EXEC dbo.FollowUnfollowUser @UserIdF,@UserId,1

                            FETCH NEXT FROM csrauto INTO @UserId   
                            END   

                            CLOSE csrauto   
                            DEALLOCATE csrauto

                FETCH NEXT FROM csrAutoFollow INTO @UserIdF   
            END         
        CLOSE csrAutoFollow   
    DEALLOCATE csrAutoFollow
```

Please let me know whether this can also be improved.

Answer (score 0):

"Transport Level Error" means that the computer from which the stored procedure was called has lost network connectivity with the Database server that the stored procedure lives on.  It has nothing to do with the code of the procedure.

You need to have your network admin look into the problem.